# Textarea changes size of its cell when editing

Tags: css, textarea, css-tables, jeditable

When I start editing textarea in a table cell (I use DataTables+jeditable), cell height and/or width slightly increases and all cells to the bottom/right change their positions. Also in cells with much text appears vertical scrollbar. How to avoid this?
Style:

```
textarea {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    resize: none;
}

table.display {
    font: 14px "Lucida Console";
    color: black;
    border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #888;
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to better demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Table cells in fiddle aren't editable. Here is full source: http://www.filedropper.com/table_3